# HP CP1025 printer needs foo2zjs-z3 {printer driver}

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi-os-buster

The printer works fine with Ubuntu 18 and linuxMint 20.1 with the foomatic driver.
On PiOs
The installed CUPS & HPLIP result in a strange colour for Black

The result from dpkg is
"dpkg -l hplip

ii  hplip          3.18.12+dfsg0-2+b2 armhf        HP Linux Printing and Imaging System (HPLIP) "

I can't find a way to download the driver, eg.wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz 
http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz

FAILS with

" wget -O foo2zjs.tar.gz http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
--2021-06-04 10:14:56--  http://foo2zjs.rkkda.com/foo2zjs.tar.gz
Resolving foo2zjs.rkkda.com (foo2zjs.rkkda.com)... 74.208.236.166
Connecting to foo2zjs.rkkda.com (foo2zjs.rkkda.com)|74.208.236.166|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-06-04 10:14:57 ERROR 404: Not Found."

Is there a way to update hplip or get the foomatic driver

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues with my HP CP 1215 and I found it uses "root" for the login name instead of "pi".

What I did was to change the password for "root" to the same one I use for "pi" then the installation will work correctly.

e.g.: sudo passwd root

Comment: Thanks  for sharing your experience. I'm afraid it didn't help I still can't find the right driver and the colour of black is still odd. I'm beginning to suspect the driver is only available for 64bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed poios 64bit on a pi 4 and installed HPLip then

$sudo su

#hp-setup

and chose hp color laserjet cp1025nw (not cp1025) and it works. Must be 64bit driver.

Comment: What is `poios`? I don't think you mean a village in Portugal.